# How to hide an item from a menu to logged out users (without a plugin)

Tags: menus

I want to hide an item from a menu if a user is logged out.

I am currently using the below code that achieves this using two separate menus, but to save duplication, I would like to only have to manage one nav menu.

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-in';
    } else { 
        $args['menu'] = 'logged-out';
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

Is it possible to hide just one item for a logged out user, rather than doing it the way I currently am?

Comment: what do you want to hide from one menu ?

Comment: A link which not visible to not registered user.

Comment: The "without a plugin" thing is never necessary. Such logic is independent from your design and styling and should survive a redesign of your site. Put it inside a plugin or a mu-plugin. Having hundreds of mini-plugins instead of a big `functions.php` or an extremely large plugin **does not** slow down your site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Find the class or id of the menu item that you want to hide.
suppose the class of that menu is `logged-in-menu`

Then in header.php file of your theme before closing head tag use the below code

```
<style>
<?php if(! is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    .logged-in-menu{
        display: none;
    }
<?php endif; ?>
</style>
```

Comment: This means that you are (a) querying unnecessary data and (b) is non-reversible for child themes or plugins. You might want to at least use a callback attached to `wp_head` or properly register and enqueue styles. While then it would be a somehow _ok_ solution, it would still be preferable to just conditionally switch those items off before querying the items from the DB.

Comment: For anyone thinking of using this, please don't. Use the proper menu hooks as per @chrisguitarguy answer.

Comment: This is crap. Any script kiddie can then still see your menu.

Answer (score 6):

Filter [`wp_nav_menu_objects`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/). It will contain the sorted list of nav menu items to render. Have a look at [`wp_setup_nav_menu_item`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/eb7df1379be5f7b24a6d29c1a390c1b1bf2e6183/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L732) for some properties you can use.

Here's a quick (untested) example.

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', function( array $items, object $args ) {

    if ( 'someThemeLocation' !== $args->theme_location ) {
        return $items;
    }

    return array_filter( $items, function( $item ) {
        return '/user-specific-thingy' === $item->url 
            && ! is_user_logged_in();
    } );

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This code is invalid, because `wp_nav_menu_objects` passes `array $sorted_menu_items, stdClass $args`, not `array $items, array $args`

Answer (score 6):

As @chrisguitarguy already added a more than valid answered while I was writing this answer, here's a simple *addition* to the other two answers.

The `return` value of the `wp_setup_nav_menu()` function has [a filter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/eb7df1379be5f7b24a6d29c1a390c1b1bf2e6183/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L880), which has `$menu_item` as only value provided – exactly before it is returned – and it is of type `object` and a `\stdClass` with the following `public` properties that you can check against:

- `ID`:               The term_id if the menu item represents a taxonomy term.
- `attr_title`:       The title attribute of the link element for this menu item.
- `classes`:          The array of class attribute values for the link element of this menu item.
- `db_id`:            The DB ID of this item as a nav_menu_item object, if it exists (0 if it doesn't exist).
- `description`:      The description of this menu item.
- `menu_item_parent`: The DB ID of the nav_menu_item that is this item's menu parent, if any. 0 otherwise.
- `object`:           The type of object originally represented, such as "category," "post", or "attachment."
- `object_id`:        The DB ID of the original object this menu item represents, e.g. ID for posts and term_id for categories.
- `post_parent`:      The DB ID of the original object's parent object, if any (0 otherwise).
- `post_title`:       A "no title" label if menu item represents a post that lacks a title.
- `target`:           The target attribute of the link element for this menu item.
- `title`:            The title of this menu item.
- `type`:             The family of objects originally represented, such as "post_type" or "taxonomy."
- `type_label`:       The singular label used to describe this type of menu item.
- `url`:              The URL to which this menu item points.
- `xfn`:              The XFN relationship expressed in the link of this menu item.
- `_invalid`:         Whether the menu item represents an object that no longer exists.

So a simple callback will allow you to use some conditional logic and then maybe exclude an item:

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu', function( \stdClass $item ) {
    # Check conditionals, and invalidate an item in case
    $item->_invalid = is_user_logged_in() 
        && 'post' === $item->object
        && 'post_type' === $item->type
        # && … whatever you need to check for your invalidation of an item
    ;

    return $item;
} );
```

The exclusion logic lives inside the `_invalid` property and is executed by the [`_is_valid_nav_menu_item( $item )`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/eb7df1379be5f7b24a6d29c1a390c1b1bf2e6183/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L603-L605) function that is a callback used when [nav menu items are retrieved](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/eb7df1379be5f7b24a6d29c1a390c1b1bf2e6183/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L678-L682). It uses it inside a `array_filter()` to reduce the number of items depending on this *flag*.

---

As extension to @MD Sultan Nasir Uddin solution: While a CSS only solution will work, goal should be to not even have the data in this request, in the database query and in the render pipeline. For a complete answer, here still is the *how*: Example using [`wp_add_inline_style()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style) to inline the styles and [PHP heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) for readability:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Hide menu items for logged in users */

# Add class:
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', function( Array $args ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() )
        $args['menu_class'] .= '  logged-in';
    return $args;
} );

# Add inline styles
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {

    $styles = <<<STYLES
.logged-in .special-item {
    display: none;
}
STYLES;

    wp_add_inline_style( 'custom-style', $styles );
} );
```

You could probably just use the `body` classes to find a `logged-in` or similar class for a more specific target as well – instead of adding an additional class like above.

Comment: That `_invalid` thing is nifty.

Comment: @chrisguitarguy It is! And I did not know about it unless you posted the answer and I read through source. Only thing I am unsure now is if it should not just be `false` when you want to drop something.

Answer (score 2):

After that I make it done using css nth child the procedure is

```
add_action('wp_head','hide_menu');

function hide_menu() { 
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        //
    } else {
        $output="<style> .menu li:nth-child(3) { display: none; } </style>";
    }
    echo $output;
}
```

Thanks all of you for your effort :)

Comment: This won't work if the menu item moves position.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea of just hiding menu items with CSS as they would still be visible using the code inspector on the page. For anyone looking for a more secure way of removing menu items, this should do the trick:

**In this example I want to remove a "Downloads" menu item for anyone that is not currently logged in.**

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'remove_menu_items' ), 10, 2 );
```

```
function remove_menu_items( $items, $args ) {

    // If you need to remove several menu items, then it's good practice to set a variable for the check beforehand so that it's not running the same check function repeatedly.
    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    foreach ( $items as $item_index => $item ) {
        // Remove "Downloads" menu item when not logged in
        if ( $item->title == 'Downloads' ) {
            if ( !$logged_in ) {
                unset($items[$item_index]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jamio answer I agree that if you just `display:none` the menu its still accessible thru `inspect element`, therefore I come up with the solution that if you want to hide the nav menus based on their class you can use `classes[0]`  instead of `title` so that you can now just add a class on menu instead on setting each menu thru code

```
 add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'remove_menu_items', 10, 2 );
function remove_menu_items( $items, $args ) {

    $logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    foreach ( $items as $item_index => $item ) {
        // Remove menu item with "hide_when_logout" class when not logged in
        if ( $item->classes[0] == 'hide_when_logout' ) {
            if ( !$logged_in ) {
                unset($items[$item_index]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Then in header.php file of your theme before closing head tag use the below code
//https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233667/how-to-hide-an-item-from-a-menu-to-logged-out-users-without-a-plugin
    <?php
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
       $output="<style>.menu-item-8685 {display: none !important;}</style>";
echo $output;
    } else {  
         echo '<script>alert("Welcome vistor")</script>';
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: That's a combination of the accepted answer and Iqbal's answer?

Comment: yes this is a answer | and worked perfect with me ...