# Hide an item from a menu to some users

Tags: menus

I want to use the below code from an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/233680/25187) of @kaiser, but I don't understand how to use it in a real situation. An example here would be appreciated.

BTW, I don't see many Q&A about the `wp_setup_nav_menu` filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu', function( \stdClass $item ) {
    # Check conditionals, and invalidate an item in case
    if ( 
        is_user_logged_in() 
        && 'post' === $item->object
        && 'post_type' === $item->type
        # && … whatever you need to check for your invalidation of an item
    )
        $item->_invalid = TRUE;

    return $item;
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls use filter `wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items` for conditionally adding or removing the menu-items.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_menu-slug_items/

See Method 2 at: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/31753/116231