# Hide menu item when users are logged in/out

Tags: menus, users

I want to be able to hide the 'My account' button when users are logged out and I want to be able to hide the 'Registration' button when users are logged in.

How would I go about doing this? I'm still a amatuer at WordPress and I'm still learning, this is what I have so far in my nav-menus.php file.

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'My Account' => 'logged-users' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'Registration' => 'not-logged-users' ) );
}
```

I know this isn't correct, but I would love some help with it, please let me know if I'm missing any information.

[image]

Comment: You may need to create a custom walker function. There doesn't seem to be anything you can pass into the `wp_nav_menu()` function to exclude specific menu items.

Comment: Hey Saint Louis,  This question has been asked many times. Wpbeginner has a few plugin ideas and on this stack there are several question with answers.  I would go with the idea of replacing the whole menu (not just items).     https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233667/how-to-hide-an-item-from-a-menu-to-logged-out-users-without-a-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I should suggest a custom walker to, not that hard at all.

starting with:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/

in the foreach loop you are able to check based on title.

in this part you will use:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

```
foreach($nav_items as $item): 
if($item->title == 'Register'):
if(is_user_logged_in()):
//Do your thing when logged in
else:
//Do your thing when not logged in
endif;
endif;

endforeach;
```

Above is an example, there are multiple ways you can do this :) hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

These are the plugins I use most often to show/hide menu items based on user role or weather the user is logged in or out:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-menus/ - Simple and intuitive.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/conditional-menus/ - For more advanced conditions and flexibility.

I also just found this one:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/ - I have not tested it but it has better reviews and was updated more recently than my first suggestion.